# Cleanup when suite got stopped in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, teardown

I have a teardown element in JMeter which cleans up some test data. It currently runs after the actual test. However, if I notice some failures and stop the suite, then the clean up is not performed and I need to do it manually. Is there any way to configure JMeter to do tearDown before getting stopped?

Comment: just put cleanup to be done at the beginning of the test.

Comment: I cannot, because it would delete the data needed by the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an emphasized paragraph in the [jMeter tearDown documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group):

> Note that by default it won't run if Test is gracefully shutdown, if
>   you want to make it run in this case, ensure you check option "Run
>   tearDown Thread Groups after shutdown of main threads" on Test Plan
>   element. If Test Plan is stopped, tearDown will not run even if option
>   is checked.

So I suppose you can't run the tearDown ThreadGroup automatically, if you stop the test (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213636/jmeter-cleanup-force-not-to-abort-before-completely-executing-a-group)).